# SQL Server query from Java gets no results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

- OS: Windows Server 2012
- Database: SQL Server 2012
- Additional Software: jdk-7u51-windows-x64, apache-tomcat-7.0.50, Ant 1.9.3

I'm migrating a website from Linux/MySQL to Windows/SQL Server. One of the problems I have: I'd like to execute the SQL query

```
SELECT 
    r.PatientID, r.StudyDate, r.StudyTime, MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy, 
    @@ROWCOUNT as 'rowcount' 
FROM 
    report r 
INNER JOIN 
    ct_irradiation_events e ON r.rdsr_id = e.rdsr_id  
INNER JOIN 
    patient_age_categories a ON (DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) <= a.max_age_days AND DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) >= a.min_age_days AND a.description = 'Erwachsene')  WHERE MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy IS NOT NULL AND r.DeviceObserverUID = '2.25.80710267121025297646217319020776291293' AND ProcedureCodeShort = 'CTBTHABDA'AND e.CTAcquisitionType != 'Constant Angle Acquisition' AND DATEDIFF(day, '2013-11-20', r.StudyDate) >=0 AND DATEDIFF(day, '2014-02-20', r.StudyDate) <=0;
```

When I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio, I receive the result. When executing the same in java via JDBC I do not receive a result.

How I like to do it (only a snippet of the code):

```
conn = EstablishDBConnection();
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
          String sQuery = "SELECT r.PatientID, r.StudyDate, r.StudyTime, " + measure + ", @@ROWCOUNT as 'rowcount'  FROM report r  INNER JOIN ct_irradiation_events e ON r.rdsr_id=e.rdsr_id  INNER JOIN patient_age_categories a ON (DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) <= a.max_age_days AND DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) >= a.min_age_days AND a.description = ?)  WHERE " + measure + " IS NOT NULL AND r.DeviceObserverUID = ? AND ProcedureCodeShort = ? AND e.CTAcquisitionType != 'Constant Angle Acquisition' AND DATEDIFF(day, ?, r.StudyDate) >=0 AND DATEDIFF(day, ?, r.StudyDate) <=0;";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
pst.setString(1, agedescription);
pst.setString(2, devicecode);
pst.setString(3, proccode);
pst.setString(4, date_from);
pst.setString(5, date_until);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
noOfValues = rs.getInt("rowcount");
servlet_context.log("noOfValues: " + noOfValues);
DBValues = new double[noOfValues];

while (rs.next()) {
  JSONArray jRow = new JSONArray();
  jRow.put(rs.getDate("StudyDate").toString() + " " + rs.getTime("StudyTime").toString());
  jRow.put(rs.getDouble(measure));
  jRow.put(rs.getString("PatientID"));
  jData.put(jRow);
  DBValues[i] = rs.getDouble(measure);
  i++;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
conn = EstablishDBConnection();
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
                pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT r.PatientID, r.StudyDate, r.StudyTime, MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy, @@ROWCOUNT as 'rowcount' FROM report r INNER JOIN ct_irradiation_events e ON r.rdsr_id=e.rdsr_id  INNER JOIN patient_age_categories a ON (DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) <= a.max_age_days AND DATEDIFF(day, r.PatientsBirthDate, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation) >= a.min_age_days AND a.description = 'Erwachsene')  WHERE MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy IS NOT NULL AND r.DeviceObserverUID = '2.25.80710267121025297646217319020776291293' AND ProcedureCodeShort = 'CTBTHABDA'AND e.CTAcquisitionType != 'Constant Angle Acquisition' AND DATEDIFF(day, '2013-11-20', r.StudyDate) >=0 AND DATEDIFF(day, '2014-02-20', r.StudyDate) <=0;");
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

The variable "measure" is defined further up in the code. However, both versions do not give me a result and finnaly I get java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to read the the empty result.

Other queries work just fine, so the connection to the data base works (at least partly). I don't have any other error in the logs expect from:

```
Feb 20, 2014 3:49:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: The result set has no current row.
Feb 20, 2014 3:49:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RDSRServlet] in context with path [/RDSRServlet] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.ksa.rdsr.web.DatabaseJSON.getCtTimeline(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you for any help!

**Edit**

Query that works:

```
String sQuery = "SELECT id, DeviceObserverName, DeviceObserverUID FROM devices WHERE Modality = ? ORDER BY DeviceObserverName ASC, id ASC;";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
            pst.setString(1, modcode);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

measure is MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy as can be seen in the second try i made.

Comment: Are you setting these intentionally as strings: `pst.setString(4, date_from);`, `pst.setString(5, date_until);` ? Also, show what measure is.

Comment: yes. it works on linux/mysql. i'm not an expert, but because the second try (where i copied the query directly and do not use setString) works, i assume the problem might be with the settings.

Comment: Following on peter.petrov's idea: being strings that must be converted into dates, are you sure there isn't anything preventing your driver from building correct dates from your string?  Have you tried passing Date objects into those parameters?  Like `pst.setDate(4, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", "2013-11-20"))`?

Comment: Ërror: simpleDateFormat can not be converted to Date and when using Date i get the error: can not be converted to java.sql.date. I get the strings from the user input and in the linux/mysql version it works...

Comment: I think Jorge_B meant `pst.setDate(4, (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse("2013-11-20"));` but typed it wrong.

Comment: I still get an error: no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date). When I remove the two dates from the WHERE clause i still don't get any rows back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that

```
noOfValues = rs.getInt("rowcount");
```

came before

```
rs.next()
```

I have to change to code then it'll work. I'll store the results in an ArrayList so I don't have to know the number of results at the beginning.
Thanks anyway.